# Strange errors from Excel, when running VBA-macros

Tags: windows, vba, microsoft-office, office365

The macro stops before execution, points to a `Trim(...)` call (a VBA built-in function) and says:

[image]

*Extra tag: 'Can't find project or library'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough this has NOTHING to do with `Trim()`... or even **any** other statement in VBA.

The important thing here is "library"

- Stop any running code.
- Open Visual Basic Editor (Alt-F11, VBE)
- Open the "References" dialog with `Menu: Tools > References...`
- Find any and all `MISSING:`  references, remove the reference forming tick `[v]`for these, or make sure to install the missing library.

An example shown here:
[image]

*One might wish to call this "the result of bad coding".*

**Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/can-t-find-project-or-library

Comment: This document requires a .dot template.

Comment: Because? Will that really IMPROVE **the error handling** and **specify the root cause of the problem** better?